# Does not Go back after pressing device back button in fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have five fragment ***f1***,***f2***,***f3***,***f4***,***f5***. I am going f1 to f2 and f2 to f3 and f3 to f4 and f4 to f5 and go back on f3 but i don`t want to go back after f3

Plz help me.

Comment: Simply press back button once again ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

If your Problem is not resolved by this, then Look at the

> getFragmentManager().popBackStack()

methods (there are several to choose from)
[getFragmentManager().popBackStack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack)